# Need help on Mongo Db Query to fetch data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given an existing mongo db collection named **users** with some documents in it which looks like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611a11a09500700009d09a12"),
    "userId" : "abc",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-14T07:22:00.535Z"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "isEligible" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611a11a09500700009d09a13"),
    "userId" : "abc",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-15T07:20:00.535Z"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "isEligible" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611a11a09500700009d09a14"),
    "userId" : "def",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-15T07:22:00.535Z"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "isEligible" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611a11a09500700009d09a15"),
    "userId" : "abc",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-16T07:18:00.535Z"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "isEligible" : true
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611a11a09500700009d09a16"),
    "userId" : "abc",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-16T07:20:00.535Z"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "isEligible" : true
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611a11a09500700009d09a17"),
    "userId" : "def",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-16T07:22:00.535Z"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "isEligible" : true
}
```

Apart from the keys mentioned in each of the documents above, there can be multiple other keys as well.

Here, I want to write a query that does the following operations and return the data:

1. Pick records with createdAt greater than or equal to "2021-08-15T00:00:00.000Z"
2. For each userId, return only the latest record i.e. record sorted by createdAt in desc order.
3. The returned document should have all the keys which are present in the original document. The number of keys can be much more than shown in the document. So, the query should automatically return all the keys.

Below is the sample output which is required:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611a11a09500700009d09a16"),
    "userId" : "abc",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-16T07:20:00.535Z"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "isEligible" : true
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("611a11a09500700009d09a17"),
    "userId" : "def",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-08-16T07:22:00.535Z"),
    "isActive" : true,
    "isEligible" : true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aggregation stage:

- First `$match` to get only documents where date is great or equal than desired date.
- Then `$sort` to set on first position values on desc order.
- And last `$group` by `userId` getting only the first value (as is ordered by `-1`, the first value will be according to `desc` order)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "createdAt": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2021-08-15T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "createdAt": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userId",
      "createdAt": {
        "$first": "$createdAt"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wHOu1FdI1Ov)

Also, if get `ObjectId` on final result is important for you, you can also add one stage like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-Wo72kW0i-0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just an update, in your answer we need to mention all the keys which we need to return in the "$project" operator manually. But, I want the query to return all the keys automatically as the number of keys can be large in number. I have also updated the question with more clear instructions and would appreciate if you can provide an update on the solution for the same.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qqm97cWKnOn). Note that I've added a new value `newValue` which is shown if exists, otherwise will be null. But you have to add manually all options into `$project` or alternativelly set values into `data` field like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PWOtytgwlnN).

Comment: Since the no. of keys can be large, It would be difficult to add all the options into $project manually, I would want the query to group the data by userId and select the latest entry for each userId and return all of the keys for the latest record as shown in the sample response.

Comment: Then you can use [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dj6jDWZjN53) using `$replaceRoot`. If it works for you I can edit my answer.

Comment: The query mentioned by you which uses $replaceRoot returns the result in the same format as desired. But, it does not maintain the sorted order on createdAt. When I ran the query multiple times, records were not sorted in the decreasing order of createdAt. You can see the same on https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q4A0UJ_E4u2

Comment: Solved the issue, using another sort operation on the data as shown in this https://mongoplayground.net/p/BhEHMF5q3TH. It works, but I am not sure if this query is optimised enough to work with large data sets.